# I want to show a single thing of a row (PHP)

Tags: php

I just one to show one thing. Randomly generated with an ID. Every ID has a string of text. I want to show the string only. I get an error when I try this:

```
$RandInt=rand(1, 2);
$query="SELECT 'text' FROM quotestable WHERE 'ID' = $RandInt"; 
mysql_result($query, 1);
```

Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: Remove your quotes from 'text' and 'id'. Also, your query never gets executed.

Comment: You are not even executing your query. [mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) expects a resultset object while you are sending it a string. You first need to execute your query and then pass the resultset to `mysql_result()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
>   removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension
>   should be used.

You execute a query as follows:

```
// (text and ID should be escaped using backticks, since they are variables)
$query = "SELECT `text` FROM quotestable WHERE `ID` = $RandInt"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And then fetch a row from the `$result`:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And then use the `$row` fetched wherever you want:

```
echo $row["text"];
```

Comment: `text` and `ID` should be escaped using backticks `

Comment: Yes, you're right. The `'` would imply that `'text'` is a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

> This extension is **deprecated** as of **PHP 5.5.0**, and is **not** recommended
>   for writing **new** code as it will be removed in the future.

Besides of the fact that you're using deprecated functions:

#1 Your query has some mistakes:

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM quotestable WHERE id = '$RandInt'";
```

- Remove the ' from text, add ' to $RandInt

#2 You aren't executing your query, do:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_result($result,1);
```

Instead of using deprecated functions, you **should** use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php).

Comment: Don't **encourage** using a deprecated database API.

Answer (score 0):

```
myslq_connect('localhost','db_username','db_password');  //Your db criterias
$RandInt=rand(1, 2);
$query="SELECT text FROM quotestable WHERE 'ID' = $RandInt"; 
$result = mysql_result($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo $row['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

User mysql_query() before mysql_result()

```
$RandInt=rand(1, 2);
$query="SELECT text FROM quotestable WHERE ID = $RandInt"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_result($result, 1);
```

**but i suggest you to use `"mysqli_"` functions as `"mysql_"` functions are deprecated**

Comment: `mysql_query($query);` maybe? Also, I'm not sure whether single quotes around the column name is valid.